# Keyboard keeps closing after user taps on input

Tags: android, ios, react-native

The problems => https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KwBWMVsj-0PFzt9cLfLuZ9cTvkqjIob8

This is my code

```
export default function TextInp(props) {
  const [ansVal, setAnsVal] = useState(props.data.ans);

  const answer = (ans) => {
    setAnsVal(ans);
    props.answer(ans);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        style={props.free ? styles.freeContainer : styles.container}
        onChangeText={(text)=>answer(text)}
        defaultValue={ansVal}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

PS. the TextInput is inside `ScrollView`. I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: It happens as you are updating state and due to your component is re-render on every key pressed.

Comment: maybe it's because you are updating props can you comment that and try once

Comment: I know the problem now. It's because TextInp was rerendered when the answer change. 
There is any solution for keep changing the answer.